# rich:autocomplete not working

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces, jsf-1.2

We are upgrading from jsf 1.2 to jsf 2. 
We are using apache myfaces 2.1 and rich faces 4.3.

Below is the xhtml code prior to migration :

```
<h:inputText id="#{userSearch}" value="#{bean.input}"/>
<rich:suggestionbox for="#{userSearch}" var="rslt" suggestionAction="#{bean.getSearchList}">                                    

</rich:suggestionbox>
```

As per migration doc , replaced `<rich:suggestionbox>` with `<rich:autocomplete>.`
Following is the xhtml code :

```
<rich:autocomplete mode="ajax" autocompleteMethod="#{bean.getSearchList}" />
```

Below is the getSearchList method

```
  public List<CustomObject> getSearchList(String searchNow) {


  }
```

The `<rich:autocomplete>` component exists inside a custom component which is invoked like this  :

```
 <example:SearchUsr bean="#{someOtherObject.bean}"/>
```

The issue i am facing is , when an input is entered inside `<rich:autocomplete>` , ajax call happens but i am am getting below exception : 
Target Unreachable, identifier 'bean' resolved to null.

I printed the value of bean (of bean.getSearchList ) inside xhtml and it is not null.

Am i missing anything while using `<rich:autocomplete>` ? Please help.

**EDIT 1 :**
When the autocompleteMethod is invoked like this : `#{masterBean.object2.object3.getSearchList}`, this issue is not observed where masterBean is the one defined in faces-config.xml with session scope. Also autocompleteMethod  must accept String argument and not object.
So is it that we cannot invoke autocompleteMethod on an intermidiate object ? It has to be a bean defined in JSF ? It is strange , but I am observing the same behaviour.

**EDIT 2 :** 
While trying to search for an answer , got this link which states the same issue : [autocomplete method does not resolve bean if ui:included and only one parameter provided](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-11469)
It gives two options : define autocomplete method with 3 parameters , use a composite component, rather than a ui:inlcude.

Comment: With custom component you mean a facelet custom component or a composite component?

Comment: @L-Ray:Its a facelet cutom component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As evident from EDIT 2 , the autocomplete method signature is changed as :

`public List<CustomObject> getSearchList(FacesContext context, UIComponent uiComp,String searchNow)` , and the issue is resolved.